# SFML throws exception on first line of main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sfml

I just started a project with SFML (my first one, thus the problems)
And when I run the program it throws an AccessViolationException on the first line of the code.
I'm using this example code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!"); // Dies here
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program dies after the first line is executed.
This is the exception information thrown:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0F09EEB6 (sfml-system-d-2.dll)in 
GameFromTutorial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCD8.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Some of the configurations I did (following the tutorial and instructions in their site):
Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

```
C:\libs\SFML-2.3.1\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)
```

Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies

```
sfml-system-d.lib;sfml-window-d.lib;sfml-graphics-d.lib;sfml-audio-d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

VC++ Directories->Include Directories:

```
sfml-system-d.lib;sfml-window-d.lib;sfml-graphics-d.lib;sfml-audio-d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

VC++ Directories->Library Directories

```
C:\libs\SFML-2.3.1\lib;C:\libs\boost_1_58_0\libs;$(LibraryPath)
```

In [VC++ Directories->Include Directories] what I gave is when I'm in debug configuration.
The Release configuration doesn't have the '-d' post-fix, double checked.

Edit: I put the sfml .dll files into the debug folder in my project (following orders from tutorial, guess you can't add references in c++ like you can in c# so it seems) to fix some reference error it gives when you try to run.
I tried removing the non '-d' files from the folder and it changed nothing.

I gave every piece of information I have on this,
If there's something more I can give, just comment.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you follow the part of the installation instructions that say ”If there's no SFML package compiled for your version of Visual C++, you will have to build SFML yourself” and build it yourself?

Comment: But as far as I know, you don't have to comiple and build the source code yourself...

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you're talking about the DLL files?

Comment: The Visual Studio *2013* pre-built binaries (dlls and libs) you can download off the SFML website will not work in Visual Studio *2015*.